# how to perform an https get request via http client?

Tags: java, android, httpclient

I am trying to make a GET request via an https end point, I am not sure if there are any special treatment that is needed, but below is my code:

```
String foursquareURL = "https://api.foursquare.com/v2/venues/search?ll=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&client_id="+CLIENT_ID+"&client_secret="+CLIENT_SECRET;
            System.out.println("Foursquare URL is " + foursquareURL);


try {
                Log.v("HttpClient", "Preparing to create a request " + foursquareURL);
                URI foursquareURI = new URI(foursquareURL);
                HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
                HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(new HttpGet(foursquareURI));
                content = response.getEntity().getContent();
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(content));
                String strLine;
                String result = "";
                while ((strLine = br.readLine()) != null)   {
                      result += strLine;
                }

                //editTextShowLocation.setText(result);
                Log.v("result of the parser is", result);

              } catch (Exception e) {
                  Log.v("Exception", e.getLocalizedMessage());
              }
```

Comment: it always hits the exception, saying api.foursquare.com and it says address family not supported by protocol

Comment: there is nothing specific to do with HTTPS (as far server certificate are accepter by Android, which is another story). Is the problem specific to HTTPS? have you tried with another URL on another wibe site with and without HTTPS?

Comment: hmmm...I havent really tried with others besides this URL with https and I am on 2.2.3

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this approach will work on Android, but we saw this same problem in server-side Java using HttpClient with HTTPS URLs. Here is how we solved the problem:

First, we copied/adapted an implementation of the class EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory into our own code base. You can find the source here:

http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/httpcomponents/oac.hc3x/trunk/src/contrib/org/apache/commons/httpclient/contrib/ssl/EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory.java?view=markup

With that class in place, we then create our new HttpClient instances with:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
mHttpClient = httpClient;
Protocol easyhttps = new Protocol("https", new EasySSLProtocolSocketFactory(), 443);
Protocol.registerProtocol("https", easyhttps);
```

The use of the EasySSLProtocolSocketsfactory will allow your HttpClient to ignore any certificate failures/isses when making the request.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [`AndroidHttpClient`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/net/http/AndroidHttpClient.html). It's essentially an alternative to `DefaultHttpClient` which will register some commonly used schemes (including HTTPS) for you behind the scenes when you create it.

You should then be able to execute `HttpGet`s using this an instance of this client and it will handle the SSL for you if your URL indicates an 'https' scheme. You shouldn't need to mess around with registering your own SSL protocols / schemes etc.